# Does removing someone from Skype also "un-share" your contact details?

Tags: skype, privacy, contacts

I've accidentally added an unknown person on Skype, and immediately after, in the chat box, I saw this, as usual:

> [Me] has shared contact details with [Stranger]

I've immediately removed them, but has this reversed the above process as well?

Comment: If they viewed your contact information they could have simply copied the information, but they can no longer view the information through Skype, if that is what you are asking.

Comment: No, it was a 4-second interval, during which they were offline anyway... thank you very much, Ramhound!